# Edit form not showing image as populated

Tags: php

I want to create a from to change the image for a record in a table. When I load in the image to the form the image appears to be there but the file selector control text says "no file chosen". What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body> 
    <main>
        <form name="EditForm" action="test-save-edit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
$post_id = trim($_GET["id"]);
require_once "config.php";
try{
    $sql1 = "select picture from images where post_id=:post_id";    
    if($stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql1)){
        $stmt1->bindParam(":post_id", $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
        if($stmt1->execute()){
            if($stmt1->rowCount() > 0){
                $i = 0;
                while($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()){
?>
            <input type="file" name="image<?php echo ++$i ?>" value="<?php echo base64_encode($row1['picture']) ?>"/>
<?php
                }
            }
        }
        unset($stmt1);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    var_dump($e->getCode());
}
?>
            <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont show an image in an `<input>` tag. Thats what you use to ask the user to pick an image from their system to send to you on the server

Comment: A file input doesn't contain the actual file contents, it only contains a reference to the file on the client when then have selected one, which it then uses when the form is submitted. You can't populate that. You should leave it empty and let the user select a new image if they want. You can always just output the current image in an img-tag next to the input to show what image currently is used.